# CSS: Anything but Content fixed

Tags: css, layout, fixed

I'm trying to make a layout where the banner, the navigation and footer always stay fixed while you can scroll the content. I have seen some kinda similar layouts here but the actual page content is not limited there. What I want now is to center anything, but you better you maybe need something visual - what I got so far:

html

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="nav1"></div>
        <div id="nav2"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: black;
}

#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#nav2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLhd6sno/1/

When scrolling I want only the content in the white area to move, also I cant figure out how to disable overflow without breaking that layout. Maybe you have an idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it that relies on absolute positioning.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
}

#banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#main {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 30px;
}

#nav1 {
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
}

#nav2 {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 150px;
    right: 100px;
    background-color: tan;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/k9nsvt3t/

If you shrink the height, you will see a scroll bar appear around the content area,
which may do the trick.  The rest of the page elements are static regardless of the
amount of content in the main area.